# File nesting in solution explorer of ASP.NET Core application

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

when i created ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Page template project, every .cshtml and their .cs file are splitted. I don't know why, before few minutes its working fine but i can't remember what i did. Maybe SDK or settings of Visual Studio. I don't know. Here are screenshot preview of my problem. On the left side is my solution explorer and on the right side is what i want.

[image]

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. you need to enable file nesting in the solution explorer.
just click that button in the image:

[image: File nesting explantaion]